# Variable in Angular http jsonp config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using http.jsonp to make cross domain calls and everything works fine, My config object is as below:

```
 var config = {
            params: {
                action: "query",
                prop: "revisions",
                format: "json",
                rvlimit: 50,
                titles: 'obama',//works
               // titles: val, //doesn't works
                callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"    
            }           
        };

        var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?";

        $http.jsonp(url, config).success(function(data) {
            var pages = data.query.pages;

            for (var pageid in pages)
            {        
                $scope.revisions = pages[pageid].revisions;
                break; // expect only one page
            }

            $scope.loaded = true;
        });
```

when the titles has a static value of obama, it works fine however I added an input box from where I am getting the value and I am trying to set the value of the input box to titles and load the particular feed, however it is not working. I have reproduced the issue on jsfiddle,

Any Ideas how to fix this/

**http://jsfiddle.net/L4qZZ/**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to fetch the contents after the user hits the "Go" button.

The problem with your code is that you are using `val` to set the title instead of `$scope.val`.

If you update that and then correct the code to make the HTTP request when user clicks the button, your data is fetched as expected.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFhv2/) that demonstrates the solution.

Just type "obama" into the input and click the button to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

since you are not using $scope for getting the `ng-model` values, use `$scope.val` instead of `val`

Try this out

```
var config = {
    params: {
        action: "query",
        prop: "revisions",
        format: "json",
        rvlimit: 50,
        titles: $scope.val,
        callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"    
    }           
};
```

Comment: This will not work since the `HTTP` request is made once the controller loads. At that time `$scope.val` will be empty and thus there will be no result fetched. See my fiddle for the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to reorganize your code a little. Move data loading functionality into a service like this one:

```
app.factory('Wiki', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
        loadData: function (title) {

            var deferred = $q.defer(),
            config = {
                params: {
                    action: "query",
                    prop: "revisions",
                    format: "json",
                    rvlimit: 50,
                    titles: title,
                    callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
                }
            },
            url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?";

            $http.jsonp(url, config).success(function(data) {
                var pages = data.query.pages;
                for (var pageid in pages) {
                    deferred.resolve(pages[pageid].revisions);
                    break;
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

And then you can use it like this in controller:

```
app.controller('HistoryController', function($scope, Wiki) {
    $scope.loaded = false;
    $scope.getData = function(val) {
        Wiki.loadData(val).then(function(data) {
            $scope.loaded = true;
            $scope.revisions = data;
        });
    }
    $scope.getData('obama');
});
```

Using services makes everything more flexible when you deal with data.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L4qZZ/1/

Comment: That's exactly how I am doing that, I just created a fiddle to illustrate the problem, however question to you is that can this be solved without using a promise like how callmekatootie did.

Comment: If callmekatootie did what you want, what is the question then?

Comment: He illustrated it just as like data in a controller, I have my code like you have organized into a service and then service being called in a controller. So my question is, using your approach how can I solve this problem without using a promise. Hope I am clear.